# Joomla - Kunena Error "Duplicate. Identical message has been ignored."

Tags: php, joomla, forum

I'm getting this error when trying to add posts as admin in Kunena forum. The post is not a duplicate so I don't understand why it is giving me this error. Is there something I can change to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, ensure you are running the latest version of Kunena (3.0.2) and Kunena plugins, along with the latest version of your Joomla series (2.5.14 or 3.1.5)

If you're running Kunena 1.6.5 and Joomla 1.7, then there are known issues with what you have reported, and thus my first point most definitely applies.

If you're using JomSocial and the JomSocial Activity Stream, again, ensure you running the latest version else try disabling the Activity stream extension to see if this solves the problem.

If you're using the Kunena/JomSocial plugin, then in its configuration set "**Core Application**" to "**Yes**" *(default is "No")*

If none of these fix your problem, then I would suggest reporting the error to the Kunena dev team.

Hope this helps